# How to prevent MySQL Union from using Full Table Scan?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, union

I have written this query using Union to fetch results from 3 different tables. The `Explain` shows that it performs 2 full table Scans. How can I optimise this query so that it doesn't perform full table Scan? This is the visual representation of the Explain [See Explain image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gjvX.png). [Explain Results part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCE9N.png) [Explain Results part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHM8p.png)

```
                  (SELECT f.name, f.description, f.location, f.copyright, f.location, f.orientation, f.cws_asset_key, pst.title, f.related_media_key, f.media_type, f.is_visible_at_press, f.created_at, 'content' AS 'type' 
              FROM ContentRelatedMedia f 
              INNER JOIN Content c ON f.content_id = c.id 
              INNER JOIN ParentSeries ps ON c.parent_series_id = ps.id 
              INNER JOIN ParentSeriesTitle pst ON pst.parent_series_id = ps.id 
              WHERE ps.is_visible_at_press = true
              AND f.is_visible_at_press = true
              AND ps.company_id = :company 
              AND f.is_archived = false 
              AND f.media_type = 'image' 
              AND (f.name LIKE '%' :name '%'
              OR f.description LIKE '%' :description '%'
              OR pst.title LIKE '%' :title '%')
              )
              UNION 
              (SELECT ff.name, ff.description, ff.location, ff.copyright, ff.location, ff.orientation, ff.cws_asset_key, pst.title, ff.related_media_key, ff.media_type, ff.is_visible_at_press, ff.created_at, 'season' AS 'type' 
              FROM SeasonRelatedMedia ff
              INNER JOIN Season s ON ff.season_id = s.id
              INNER JOIN ParentSeries ps ON s.parent_series_id = ps.id
              INNER JOIN ParentSeriesTitle pst ON pst.parent_series_id = ps.id
              WHERE ps.is_visible_at_press = true
              AND ff.is_visible_at_press = true
              AND ps.company_id = :company
              AND ff.is_archived = false 
              AND ff.media_type = 'image' 
              AND (ff.name LIKE '%' :name '%'
              OR ff.description LIKE '%' :description '%'
              OR pst.title LIKE '%' :title '%')
              )
              UNION 
              (SELECT fff.name, fff.description, fff.location, fff.copyright, fff.location, fff.orientation, fff.cws_asset_key, pst.title, fff.related_media_key, fff.media_type, fff.is_visible_at_press[![enter image description here][1]][1], fff.created_at, 'parent_series' AS 'type' 
              FROM ParentSeriesRelatedMedia fff
              INNER JOIN ParentSeries ps ON fff.parent_series_id = ps.id
              INNER JOIN ParentSeriesTitle pst ON pst.parent_series_id = ps.id
              WHERE ps.is_visible_at_press = true
              AND fff.is_visible_at_press = true
              AND ps.company_id = :company 
              AND fff.is_archived = false 
              AND fff.media_type = 'image' 
              AND (fff.name LIKE '%' :name '%'
              OR fff.description LIKE '%' :description '%'
              OR pst.title LIKE '%' :title '%')
              )
```

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, you would need to add the missing indexes. Without knowing which indexes you have, we cannot tell you which are missing (I would check if you have an index on e.g. `SeasonRelatedMedia.season_id` and `ParentSeriesRelatedMedia.parent_series_id`). But even if you have, your numbers do not look as if a full table scan is a bad idea here. The first join after the full table scan produces 17 rows, while the path on the right produced 13k rows. If these numbers are correct (they are guesses by MySQL), it looks like a good execution path. You can try different ones by using `force index`.

Comment: Thank @Solarflare for the comment. I have these indexes on the tables. On ContentRelatedMedia I have (1) related_media_key (2) cws_asset_key (3) location. On SeasonRelatedMedia I have (1) related_media_key (2) cws_asset_key (3) location. On ParentSeriesRelatedMedia I have (1) related_media_key (2) cws_asset_key (3) location.

Comment: Your execution plan implies that you have an index on `ContentRelatedMedia.content_id`, which you didn't list. Please add the explain output (write `explain ` infront of your query and post the result) so we do not have to guess. Also, again, your query might already be fine as it is, a full table scan in a table with 38k rows that produces 17 rows can (and probably will) be a lot faster than a join that produces 13k rows.

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare . It's still slow and as the table grows very fast. It will soon be out of control.  I have attached the results of the `Explain` query here in 2 parts as I could not capture the whole in one part.  I have attached the image to the main post as I could not upload images here.

Comment: Have you actually added the 2 proposed indexes? According to the explain plan, you *have* an index on `f.content_id` (the index `idx_2EF8...`), but I do not know if you have the others. Please execute and `explain` 3 seperate selects (for each union) and get the timing for each part. For the 2nd union, try `FROM ParentSeries ps straight_join Season s ON s.parent_series_id = ps.id straight_join SeasonRelatedMedia ff ON ff.season_id = s.id INNER JOIN ParentSeriesTitle pst ON ...`. If you have the indexes, it should be executed as you want it, so check if it is, and if it's faster.

Comment: By the way: a different question you could ask would be "how to optimize your query" (and not: "how can I make my query execute it the way I assume is the best"). But start by testing the `straight_join`-code, both in union and seperate, and get the times for each version.